# Distinct Count Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table below:

```
 Item    Status1    Status2
-----------------------------
  A       Good       NULL
  A       Good       NULL
  A       Good       NULL
  A       Bad        Good

  B       Bad        Good
  B       Good       NULL

  C       Good       NULL
  C       Good       NULL      
  C       Good       NULL

  D       Bad        Good
```

Now, I'm thinking off writing a `query` which gives me the result below:

```
 Item     Good     Bad
-----------------------------
  A        4        1
  B        2        1
  C        3        0
  D        1        1
```

Distinct in the Item column and the count of Good and Bad for each Item where `NULL` is not counted.

The column name can be of anything (I just kept it as Good and Bad in my second table).

Any suggestions/ideas on how to achieve my desired results?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` & do aggregation :

```
select item, sum(status = 'good'), sum(status = 'bad')
from (select item, status1 as status
      from table t
      union all
      select item, status2
      from table t
     ) t
group by item;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union all and conditional aggregation

```
select item, count(case when status1='good' then 1 end) as good,
count(case when status1='bad' then 1 end) as bad
from
(
select item , status1 from tablename
union all
select item , status2 from tablename
)A group by item
```

Answer (score 1):

use union  and case when

```
select Item, sum(case when status = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) as good, 
 sum ( case when status = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end) as bad
from (select Item, Status1 as status
      from table_name
      union all
      select Item, Status2
      from table_name
     ) t
group by Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for UNION, simply apply some logic.

```
select Item
  ,sum(case when Status1 = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end +
       case when Status2 = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) as good
  ,sum(case when Status1 = 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end +
       case when Status2 = 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end) as bad
from tab
group by Item
```

or

```
select Item
  ,count(case when Status1 = 'Good' then 1 end) +
   count(case when Status2 = 'Good' then 1 end) as good
  ,count(case when Status1 = 'Bad' then 1 end) +
   count(case when Status2 = 'Bad' then 1 end) as good
from tab
group by Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query and then apply sum function in outer query

```
select distinct(item) as item, sum(S1G+S2G) as Good,sum(S1B+S2B) as Bad from (  select item, CASE WHEN status1 ='Good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as S1G, CASE WHEN status2 ='Good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as S2G,  CASE WHEN status2 ='Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as S2B,  CASE WHEN status1 ='Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as S1B from t1 ) as b group by item
```

Here is [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fe50f/27/0)